# cocos2d-x Label Load Image like Sticker-Smile..(by html or …)

Tags: cocos2d-x, image, rendertexture

hi and sorry for my english...

i am using cocos2d-x (c++)... can i load sticker (smile) in my Label(a text mixed by image)? i know that we can load bitmap fonts by:

```
Label::createWithBMFont
```

also i know many frameworks like flash can load html texts by textbox which can contains img tags... but what is the best way for adding smile image in the text of label in cocos2d-x?? can cocos2d Label load html text like :

```
"hello<br>How Are You<img src="..." width=".." height=".." alt="..">"???
```

thanks...

Comment: Please don't put something like [SOLVED] in the title, accept an answer instead.

Comment: ok...but i can't accept it,
when i push on it, i just see this message:
"you can accept you'r own answer in 2 days"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've found my way...
we can load images and show different text formats by UIRichText...
also you can push unicode texts...
example code is:

```
auto text = cocos2d::ui::RichText::create();
const auto font = std::string("fonts/FinalFonts/Berlin.ttf");
text->pushBackElement(ui::RichElementCustomNode::create(1995, Color3B(255, 255, 255), 255, Label::createWithSystemFont(persianText01, font, 20, Size::ZERO, TextHAlignment::RIGHT, TextVAlignment::TOP)));
text->pushBackElement(ui::RichElementImage::create(1993, Color3B(255, 255, 255), 255, "icons/sticker.png"));
text->pushBackElement(ui::RichElementCustomNode::create(1994, Color3B(255, 255, 255), 255, Label::createWithSystemFont(persianText02, font, 20, Size::ZERO, TextHAlignment::RIGHT, TextVAlignment::TOP)));
text->pushBackElement(ui::RichElementImage::create(1990, Color3B(255, 255, 255), 255, "icons3/sticker.png"));
text->pushBackElement(ui::RichElementCustomNode::create(1998, Color3B(255, 255, 255), 255, Label::createWithSystemFont(persianText03, font, 20, Size::ZERO, TextHAlignment::RIGHT, TextVAlignment::TOP)));
sprite->addChild(text);
```